# Is there a way in Jenkins to get "Number of hours in RED state" for a build?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, agile, continuous-deployment

Is there a jenkins plugin or native way to measure how many hours (in a day, week or month - whatever duration feasible) the build was RED for a job?

**Background:**

I am currently working with a team and promoting trunk based development. One thing that I want to measure to check if our efforts toward "Collective code ownership" works - No. of hours in RED state.

I don't want to measure number of RED builds but instead the duration of RED because breaking the build is not important to me, but fixing is.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably write a python or shell script using jenkins rest api

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/test/api/json
```

will get you all the builds

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/test/1/api/json
```

will give you details of a particular build